# Converting model to .h5 format

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently working on a project which I used the tutorial notebook from tensorflow seq2seq2 NMT and I want to somehow save the model into .h5 format:

```
# exporting model
class Export(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(Export,self).__init__()
        self.model = model
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])])
    def translate(self, inputs):
        return self.model.translate(inputs)
```

and saving it to like this:

```
export = Export(foo_model)
tf.keras.models.save_model(export, f"/gdrive/My Drive/model-translator-.h5",
                       signatures={'serving_default': export.translate})
```

whenever I ran this code the error output is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/saving/saving_utils.py in try_build_compiled_arguments(model)
    349     if (
    350         not version_utils.is_v1_layer_or_model(model)
--> 351         and model.outputs is not None
    352     ):
    353         try:

AttributeError: 'Export' object has no attribute 'outputs'
```

Comment: got this issue too, hope we would find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Jansen, As per official documentation Signatures to save with the tf.keras.models.save_model( ) are applicable to the 'tf' format only.  Save the model using tf.saved_model.save( ). Thank You.